# Data wrangling Claims Data in R to find the total cost per member with respect to particular date

Tags: r, aggregate, data-manipulation, claims

I am currently working with claims data. I am unable to judge on how to approach this problem. Below is the sample data(claims_input):-

**claims_input**

```
 CLAIM_ID  MEM_NUMBER Year_Month PLACE_OF_SERVICE NET_PAYABLE
 6343985    123456     2011-Jan          CLINICS      55.65
 6332945    123456     2011-Jan          CLINICS      190.05
 6303844    956096     2011-Apr          CLINICS      115.00
 6320409    984659     2011-Jan          PHARMACY     92.00
 4300650    095877     2011-Jan          CLINICS      92.00
 6034750    496500     2011-Feb          PHARMACY     193.97
```

**claims_output**

```
CLAIM_ID  MEM_NUMBER Year_Month Clinics  Pharmacy 
 6343985    123456     2011-Jan  55.65    NA
 6332945    123456     2011-Jan  190.05   NA
 6303844    956096     2011-Apr  115.00   NA
 6320409    984659     2011-Jan  NA       92.00
 4300650    095877     2011-Jan  92.00    NA
 6034750    496500     2011-Feb  NA       193.97
```

The focus here is to check what is the amount claimed by each member for clinic and pharmacy with respect to a particular date.

Thank you. Looking forward to some insights.

Comment: have you tried something, like a `dplyr` or `data.table` approach?

Comment: Yes, I am looking into dplyr. But I was lost on how to frame a R-code that will match conditions in multiple rows and eventually have the desired output in different columns. I have used dplyr for row-wise aggregation.Not able to get a clarity on row to column aggregation.

Comment: I've just added a solution. Please try to be more concise and explain key concept of the desired data manipulation because some aspect are not clear to me, that's why my solution does not match your output.

Comment: Thank you. I will follow on those lines. The claim id is removed because, we are looking at claims made by each member in a particular month rather than claims itself. In case of member 59860 on Apr-15, the total claim is 95 for pharmacy.

Comment: @SabDeM - I have corrected my question to bring in more clarity. Does this help?

Comment: It helps indeed, but most likely this question is a duplicate. You should search before post a new question. Anyway I've edited my original answer. Now it should do the trick.

Comment: The reason the question was closed as "too broad" wasn't that you needed to narrow down the description. The reason was that questions describing your requirements and asking someone to explain how to write the code or provide examples or references are off-topic. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and the full text of any error messages. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/UeT2tS)].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another try, given the edited question:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
claims_output <- claims_input %>% group_by(CLAIM_ID) %>% spread(PLACE_OF_SERVICE,NET_PAYABLE)
claims_output
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]

  CLAIM_ID MEM_NUMBER Year_Month CLINICS PHARMACY
1  4300650      95877   2011-Jan   92.00       NA
2  6034750     496500   2011-Feb      NA   193.97
3  6303844     956096   2011-Apr  115.00       NA
4  6320409     984659   2011-Jan      NA    92.00
5  6332945     123456   2011-Jan  190.05       NA
6  6343985     123456   2011-Jan   55.65       NA
```

Please note that the `MEM_NUMBER` `095877` got reduced to `95877`, as the zero is left aligned. This should not be a problem, but can be fixed.

Comment: I tried to implement this solution. But the output I get is just two columns with a total sum of clinic and pharmacy amounts respectively.

Comment: Can you post some of your actual data? Perhaps with `head(dput())`, to get the actual structure

Comment: I will update the same

Comment: please do, having the structure of your dataframe would be easier to arrange for dates and members

Comment: I have made the changes in the question itself. Hope this helps.

Comment: is the `NA` in the `claims_output` your desired result then?

Comment: It can be left blank as well. My only concern here is to separate the NET_PAYABLE column with respect to clinics and pharmacy.

Comment: ok, edited the answer, let me know if it works

Comment: I get this error - Error in ungroup(., CLAIM_ID) : unused argument (CLAIM_ID)

Comment: ok try again? that should work

Comment: Its working! Let me just double check on the output. Thank you. Truly appreciate it.

Comment: anytime, if you would like to arrange per group, you can do this: `claims_output %>% arrange(MEM_NUMBER, Year_Month)`. If it DOES NOT work, please comment so I can try another option, if it does work, please consider accepting/upvoting the answer.

Comment: It works! Thank you. I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer up. But you are brilliant. Can you give a brief highlight on how the solution works?

Comment: Pretty straightforward:First, groups by claims_id, either you have some repeated, or if they are unique, keeps them in the data.frame, as not to be lost. Spread is the 'long-to-wide' version of dplyr. It takes the original columns (place of service and net payable) and checks the ids in order to construct new columns by the grouping variable from the start.

Comment: Finally, arrange, in the comments, groups by mem_group and year_month, as you might have some particular member that claimed something in the same date, and arranges on that group. As for the answer: You can accept the solution as valid via the green tickmark that appears next to the answer. It will give you reputation in SO as well

Answer (score 0):

Now it is clear. You just need the `tidyr` function `spread`:

```
 library(tidyr)
 spread(df, PLACE_OF_SERVICE, NET_PAYABLE)
  CLAIM_ID MEM_NUMBER Year_Month CLINICS PHARMACY
1  4300650      95877   2011-Jan   92.00       NA
2  6034750     496500   2011-Feb      NA   193.97
3  6303844     956096   2011-Apr  115.00       NA
4  6320409     984659   2011-Jan      NA    92.00
5  6332945     123456   2011-Jan  190.05       NA
6  6343985     123456   2011-Jan   55.65       NA
```

Comment: @saDeM  Thank you. This works as well. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` approach, which assumes your data is named `dt`. This assumes your date is already constructed as a year-month, otherwise you'll want to create a date that is year-month so that you can sum by that variable.

```
library(data.table)
# Collapse all charges by member, date, and place of service #
dt <- dt[,list('amount'=sum(amount)), by=c('member_no', 'date', 'place_of_service')]

# Reshape to wide #
dt.wide <- reshape(dt, idvar=c('member_no', 'date'), timevar='place_of_service', direction='wide') 

# Rename per your example, correcting member_no #
setnames(dt.wide,c('member_no', 'date', 'clinic', 'pharmacy'))
```